# Facebook "fb_dtsg" and "lsd" key. What are they and how can I get them?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a Facebook Business data crawl website (REACT). Currently, I'm stuck at how to get `business ad creation limit`.

When tracking Network tabs of https://business.facebook.com/settings/info?business_id=48079066xxxxxxx. I notice there is only a `POST` request have the response of limit fields. However, this quite difficult to duplicate since int required a lot of 'unknown' fields

```json
{ adAccountLimit: 3}
```

[Image of request has ad account limit creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0dv9.png)

I found a new way to achieve the same response with API:

```json
https://business.facebook.com/business/adaccount/limits/?business_id=xxxxx&__a=1&fb_dtsg=xxxxx&lsd=xxxx
```

But still, it required field `fb_dtsg` and `lsd`. I tried gg to search but no use. How can i get/generate it with client side or req from graph api ?

Comment: FYI. Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. You have to use Graph API to get data.

Comment: I have tried look at the document. But it seems like no mention in this topic

Comment: No mention of what topic?

Comment: About getting "fb_dtsg", "lsg" nor "get ad account creation limit"

Comment: Because those are not part of the Graph API. You can read about the Graph API on https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Yeah, I aware that. Do you know how to get it?When discorvery,  some facebook tools have it when authenticate and store in localStorage without make any request.

Comment: As I said Facebook does not allow you to scrape them. You have to use the Graph API

Comment: Sadly, I didn't found any instruction about getting ad creation limit :/